# onChange() should match the last typed alphabet, not the entire line every time

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Explanation:** I am using onChange function to find if someone types `@`

**Problem:** As I type it keeps on checking the entire line every time which makes typing sluggish. I want to modify my code so that it only checks the last alphabet which was typed.

**My code:**

`home.html`

```
<ion-textarea #chat [(ngModel)]="tag" rows="1" cols="10" placeholder="Type your message..." (ngModelChange)='onChange($event)'></ion-textarea>
```

`home.ts`

```
onChange(eve)
{
if(eve.match(/@/g).length > 0)
```

This is making typing experience sluggish because it checks the whole line every time, **I want it should only check the last typed alphabet**.

Comment: I really doubt that "comparing whole line" vs "comparing single character" would make a noticeable difference performance-wise. The reason for "sluggish" lies likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

Template:

```
<ion-textarea #chat [(ngModel)]="tag" rows="1" cols="10" placeholder="Type your message..." (keydown)="onType($event)"></ion-textarea>
```

Typescript:

```
onType(event) {
    if (event.key == '@') {
      console.log("@ typed")
    }
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qkeiwx)**

Comment: thank you so much, just stuck in one more issue, if possible please help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970245/autosize-textarea-with-max-5-line-limit-then-show-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use keydown event:

```
<input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">
```

Then you can handle it like this:

```
onKeydown(event) {
  if(event.key === "@")
  {  
    // your code
  }
}
```

But if you would like to just check last character in your string for onChange then you can do it this way:

```
if(eve.slice(-1) === '@') {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to find last alphabets.

```
onChange(eve) {   
  eve = eve.split('')[eve.length-1] 
  if(eve.match(/@/g).length > 0) 
  ...
}
```