# Autosize textarea with max 5 line limit, then show scrollbar

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Explanation:** In Angular 2, on my chat screen, I want to increase the size of my chat screen as I type, to max 5 lines and then show scrollbar. How do I do it?

**Problem:** Not behaving as expected. Scrollbar limit to 5 lines needs here, ideally contract, expand not working.

**Requirement:** It should expand as I type and contract as I press backspace. After 5 lines it should show scrollbar.

**My code:**

`home.ts`

```
autogrow(){
  let  textArea = document.getElementById("textarea")       
  textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  textArea.style.height = '0px';
  textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

`home.html`

```
<textarea id="textarea" (keyup)="autogrow()" ></textarea>
```

Comment: use `rows="{{rowSize}}"` attribute. and  inside your fucntion `autogrow(){ rowSize++}`

Comment: It is better if you share minimal code on stackbiltz with whatwver you have tries, then the community can fix/modify your code and share the working copy

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib any working demo ?

Comment: check this example: https://blog.invoiceberry.com/2011/03/dynamically-change-the-height-of-a-textarea-based-on-the-text-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a directive something like this:

```
    @Directive({
     selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]'
     })

export class AutoSizeDirective implements OnInit {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  onInput(target): void {
    this.adjust(target);
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target'])
  onFocus(target): void {
    this.adjust(target);
  }

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.adjust(), 100);
  }

  adjust(textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement = null): void {
    if (textArea == null) {
        textArea = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    }
    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';
    textArea.rows = 1;

    if (textArea.scrollHeight < 200) { //or whatever height you like
      textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } else {
      textArea.style.height = 200 + 'px';
    }

  }
}
```

Then in your html you just use the autosize property in the tag like so:

```
<textarea autosize .....>
```

You would have to add your directive to app.module as well.
Hope this solves your problem.